# Manipulating a PHP variable inside WP_Query in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

*** This question may be quite long so hope to bear with me ***

Was trying to group address under a particular city dynamically.

Layout sample:

[image]

So based on the sample layout above, Cupertino belongs to CA and so is displayed below it.

The city is selected inside an ACF group.

I tried to query the cities by the following code:

```
                    <?php 
                        $counter = 0; 
                        $cityArray = array();
                    ?>

                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>

                        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php   
                            $city   = get_field('city');
                            if(!in_array($city, $cityArray))
                            {   
                                $cityArray[$counter] = get_field('city');
                                $counter++;
                            }
                        ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                        <?php  
                        foreach ($cityArray as $i) 
                        {
                                $loopCity = $i;

                        ?>

<?php echo "city before loop is $i"; ?>
                            <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value'=> '$i', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

                            <?php echo "city after loop is $i"; ?>
```

The value of the `$i` variable do display as the sample below shows:

[image]

However, the WP_Query seems to not recognize the variable `$i`.

If I used the following:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value'=> 'Los Angeles', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value'=> '$i', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
```

The query outputs all address under Los Angeles.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're passing on a variable as string.

Try:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'branches_locations', 'meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value'=> $i, 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my issue. Forgot much about it cause I was long time Front-end dev.